# Determine coordinates of 3D point base on other points

Tags: geometry, 3d, surfaces

Is there any easy way to determine a coordinates of point that is marked  as BLUE SPHERE at image which one is attached into that thread. We have only  coordinates of P1,P2 and P3, we dont have a information about plane that contains those points and also we dont have  information about normal point to that plane. Is there any option to solve that problem ??

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGaBL.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByPnm.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrDb6.png)

Comment: Is there ANY information about how the blue sphere relates to anything? From the picture, it looks like the line from the blue sphere to $P_2$ is the normal of the plane. Is this correct?

Comment: @MattiP. exacly that what you say. Blue have same vertical like P1 and same horizontal like P2. I will add more images

Comment: It appears that the blue sphere is a vertex of a cuboid, that is, all three angles around it are $90^{\circ}$. If so,  its coordinates can be determined.

Comment: @Narasimham exacly cuboid, but how can I determine a coordinates if I have those information, I have only coordinates of some cuboid edges and also cuboid vertex  is there any forumla to determine that ??

Comment: OK; Three spheres with diameters $P1-P2,P2-P3, P3-P1 $  make circles intersecting concurrently  at the required point.

Answer (score 0):

Consider slant edges are of length $(p,q,r)$ meeting at cuboid corner with known base triangle positioned as a triangular pyramid.

Given sides $(a,b,c)$ of this particular triangular  pyramid base are related by the Pythagoras theorem:

$$ p^2+q^2= a^2, q^2+r^2=b^2,r^2+p^2=c^2 \,;$$

Solving these simultaneous equations

$$ p^2= (a^2-b^2+ c^2)/2, q^2 = (a^2+b^2-c^2)/2, r^2=(-a^2+b^2+c^2)/2 ;$$

Also we can find height of the pyramid using Volume and base area $\Delta$  (Brahmagupta/Heron) relation:

$$ \frac13 \Delta h = \frac16 pqr ;\, \rightarrow h= \frac{pqr}{2 \Delta}$$

With slant edge dimensions and height we can find projected slant edge lengths by Pythagoras:

$$ \sqrt{p^2-h^2},\sqrt{q^2-h^2},\sqrt{r^2-h^2}; $$

so that all coordinates of blue sphere center are now found in this configuration.